# Reverting a part of the commit in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

I have merged revisions 1,2,3 from branch A to branch B and committed the same in a single commit.
Now, I need to revert back only revision 2 from branch B.

It is difficult to revert this commit and redo the merge as there lot of commits that have been made after this.

Is there any option to do it other than manual compare and reverting the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert revision 2 from Branch A and merge it to Branch B .

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TortoiseSVN for such jobs. Going to "Show Log", right click the commit you want to revert and than "Revert changes from this revision".

Comment: I have merged a range of revisions from branch A to branch B and committed it on Branch B as a whole. So i wont be able to see the revision for 2 when trying to click on show logs on Branch B.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Well the only way which comes to my mind is to revert so hole merge (not the things after) an do the merge it again. Maybe the Merge-Log ("Show Log" -> left click on merge-commit -> in the lower file-window right click a file and "Get merge logs").